# Summation of rows based on Dropdown selection in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have a dropdown in Power BI that contains different project name such as Project One, Two, Three. I have included one formula to bring forecast value which is:

Forecast = Chase * Target%

I have created one measure that calculates forecast. The dataset contains weekly based data for Chase and Target %.  For example week 1 (Jan 01-Jan 08) Chase will be 30 and target % as 10 hence the forecast for Week 1 is 3 (30*10%)

When I select one project from dropdown list e.g. "Project One" I see the forecast value populating correctly. Same goes if I select only one project from dropdown list .

The issue arises when I select multiple projects and then the forecast value brings the maximum value instead of bringing summation to the values of all weeks of all projects.

Question: What exactly is causing the issue?

Comment: How you are handling Target as there are Target value available in each row?

Comment: Yes there are target % present for each row. Each row is distributed by day wise but in chart we want week wise

Comment: So how you will define the final target if there are target like Day-1: 100%, Day-2: 90%.....Day-7: 60%?

Comment: In database for each week target is defined. Let say week 1,2 3,& 4 have targets set as 10,15,45 and 100 respectively. Then for next month again there are 4 weeks with target as say 20,45,60,90 respectively

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/o80iRt7 in this URL see pic titled "DB Snapshot"

Comment: so one more question - for say week-1, >> project-1 chase = 50 and target 100% >> project-2 chase = 70 and target 80%. In this case, what is your expected output if you select both project 1 & 2?

Comment: Can you add the calculation of Measure 3 to your question?

Comment: @mkRabbani Output wll be week 1 : 50(50*100%) + 56 (70*80%) = 106. Basically if I select 2 projects those values of 2 projects should add up and shown in the graph. In this example 106 will appear in graph..Hope I answer your question... Same logic will go for Week 2 for those 2 projects.. If only one project is selected say Project-1 then the output on graph will be 50

Comment: @xorpower, I have updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I understand your requirement from your comments. You can achieve this through 2 step as explained below-

Step-1: Create a custom column in your data source as below-

```
row_level_forecast = finetarget[chase]/100.00 * finetarget[target]
```

[image]

Step-2: Create the final Measure as below-

```
forecast = sum(finetarget[row_level_forecast])
```

Now, use measure "forecast" in the report. This should give you the desired output.

[image]

## **ISSUE-2:** From your comments

If I understand correct, you are talking about a case where you are concern about values in columns I marked red in the below picture-

[image]

If I am correct with my understanding, you wants to fill week-3 values for Project-1 with 80/70 and for Project-2 100/90. If this is ok, just follow these following steps.

Step-1: Go to EDIT mode clicking "Transform Data" option and select the table you wants to adjust data.

Step-2: Sort your data first for project_name (ascending) then week (ascending). The output will be also as shown in the above image.

Step-3: Select column "chase" in the table and click Fill>>Down option.

[image]

Step-4: Repeat step 3 for column"target" as well.

The final output should be as below. Just move back to main report by clicking "Close and Apply". Data should be now as expected in your report.

[image]

Comment: Thanks your code works!! Is it possible that if future weeks doesn't contain any data then it should take previous week data.. Hence in my example if week 3 (future week) doesn't have any data (as it is in future) then it should take previous week 2 data maintaining summation logic that you mentioned.... Can you post a workaround for that? I am unable to find relevant DAX

Comment: i will check shortly.

Comment: Sure! Appreciate the effort :-)

Comment: Are you talking about that you have available row - "Week-3/project-1/NULL/NULL" and "Week-3/project-2/NULL/NULL"? In this case you need Week-2 value for same Project in the row with Week-3?

Comment: Yes.. So for future weeks we don't have forecast data hence we need to take previous week data as is. The addition of two projects for Future week should be same as previous week. If the value is present for future week that we DO NOT need to take previous week data. For example say Week 2 data is 100 (50 for each project ) and Week 3 data is NULL in that case Week 3 data will be 100. If week 3 contains data which is 150 then Week 3 will be 150 and not 100.. Hope I made myself clear.. if not let me know

Comment: I will add the solution as per my understanding soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217971/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-xorpower).

Answer (score 0):

When you display the forecast, put it in a grid and add the project column, the week column (e.g. Week 1) and the forecast measure. When you select your multiple projects the grid will show each of those along with the calculated measure. If this does not work, there is something wrong with your measure and you should add your measure calculation script to your question.

The measure should be simple, something like:

```
Forecast = SUM(YourTable[Chase]) * AVERAGE(YourTable[Target%])
```

Comment: Thanks for reply...https://imgur.com/a/o80iRt7 Here the Report-1, the last column in grid shows the value as 66.... If I filter the report for particular report I still see the same value

Comment: By all the identical numbers it seems the data is spread across two tables but missing a relationship. Or using "ALL" in your measure to remove the relationship.